# NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.<init>(I)V while using Parboiled

Tags: java, maven, parboiled

I have the following program, which executes a parser. This is developed in grappa (a fork of parboiled)

```
package com.test;

import org.parboiled.Parboiled;
import org.parboiled.parserunners.BasicParseRunner;
import org.parboiled.parserunners.ParseRunner;
import org.parboiled.support.ParsingResult;

public final class SampleRun
{
        public static void main(final String... args)
        {
        // 1. create a parser

        final TestGrammar parser = Parboiled.createParser(TestGrammar.class);
        // 2. create a runner
        final ParseRunner<String> runner
        = new BasicParseRunner<String>(parser.oneLine());
        // 3. collect the result

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        final ParsingResult<String> result
        = runner.run("sno101 snamegowtham");

        // 4. success or not?
        System.out.println(result.isSuccess());
        }
}
```

**TestGrammar**

```
package com.test;

import com.github.parboiled1.grappa.parsers.EventBusParser;
import org.parboiled.Rule;
import org.parboiled.support.Var;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestGrammar
    extends EventBusParser<String>
{
    protected final Map<String, String> collectedValues
        = new HashMap<String, String>();
    protected final Var<String> var = new Var<String>();

    Rule key()
    {
        return sequence(
            firstOf(ignoreCase("sno"), ignoreCase("sname")),
            var.set(match().toLowerCase()),
            !collectedValues.containsKey(var.get())
        );
    }

    Rule separator()
    {
        return optional(anyOf(":-*_ "));
    }

    Rule value()
    {
        return sequence(
            oneOrMore(testNot(wsp()), ANY),
            collectedValues.put(var.get(), match()) == null
        );
    }

    Rule oneLine()
    {
        return join(sequence(key(), separator(), value()))
            .using(oneOrMore(wsp()))
            .min(2);
    }
}
```

But, I am getting the following error when I try to execute the above program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode.<init>(I)V
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserClassNode.<init>(ParserClassNode.java:50)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.extendParserClass(ParserTransformer.java:93)
    at org.parboiled.transform.ParserTransformer.transformParser(ParserTransformer.java:63)
    at org.parboiled.Parboiled.createParser(Parboiled.java:64)
    at com.test.SampleRun.main(SampleRun.java:15)
```

I have the following **maven dependencies**

1. grappa-1.0.4.jar
2. asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar
3. guava-18.0.jar
4. jitescript-0.4.0.jar

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>parboiledprogram</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.parboiled1</groupId>
        <artifactId>grappa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Note: I am using *Eclipse Juno Service Release 2*

---

**Some attempts that didn't work**

---

I have noticed the following icon for `asm-debug-all-5.0.3.jar`, I am not sure what this icon means in eclipse juno.

[image]

1. Also, in the [**pom.xml**](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/me/qmx/jitescript/jitescript/0.4.0/jitescript-0.4.0.pom) of the dependency `jitesscript-0.4.0.jar` I have noticed relocation of the `org.objectweb.asm` package. However, the classes in that too contain the `ClassNode(int)` `jitescript` was updated is on **16-Apr-2014** whereas `asm-debug-all-5.0.3` was on **24-May-2014**
2. I have tried to remove jitescript.jar and updated the maven project and also cleaned and build it but still no use.
3. I have also tested this in KEPLER without using maven by manually including all the dependencies that are listed above. But still, I am getting the same error. This means that the problem was not with Maven but something else.

Comment: What's curious here is that if you REALLY have the asm jar the constructor ClassNode(int) exists... All that the ParserClassNode does is call `super(Opcodes.ASM5)`; I see no reason why this fails :(

Comment: I tested with a simple `AbcParser` and it worked. Can you post `TestGrammar`?

Comment: @JavaTechnical I created a project like yours and it worked. See here: http://goo.gl/WDZh1I. Try update your project, full clean and rebuild, I see no reason why this fails.

Comment: @BrunoCésar See updated question. I am getting a different icon on the asm dependency.

Comment: This icon means that maven also has the source code of this dependence. Maybe the error in your enviroment is 'cause classpath precedence, is strange. I made a change and continued working in my environment. Try to do the same. I add an exclusion to `asm-debug-all` on `grappa` and add `jitescript` dependency, version `0.3.2`.

Comment: @BrunoCésar It didn't work. Are you working in the same environment?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Yes, tested in same eclipse version. Whta's java and maven version, and your OS?

Comment: @BrunoCésar **jdk1.7.0_13** and **Windows XP 32-bit**. I am using **m2e plugin version 1.4.0.20130601-0317**

Comment: @BrunoCésar Solved, see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the presence of `dcevm.jar` present in my `jre\lib\ext` folder. The jdk which I have used for the project contains the `dcevm.jar` file and that this jar contains the package `org.objectweb.asm.tree` which `contains`ClassNode`with no constructor like ClassNode(int)`.

The jvm is using this jar instead of the jar file in the maven dependencies i.e. if there are classes that are present in any of the jar files in the JRE system library used by the project, they override the classes present in the maven jars.

Therefore, I have deleted the `dcevm.jar` from the `jre\lib\ext` and then in my eclipse preferences, I have changed the execution environment to a new one (to my jdk path, `jdk1.7.0_13`) and used at is default.

**Summary**

Such errors occur clearly because of different versions of jar files containing the class. To identify them:

1. First, search for the class (ex. `ClassNode`) in the eclipse **Open Type (Ctrl+Shift+T)** and you'll find different files with same classname and package too. You can also see where they are located.
2. Open each one and check in which the method is not found. Eliminate it.

Note: If the class is present in JRE system library, then this is likely to override the one in the maven dependency.